# MFC C++ : How to customise List?

Tags: c++, .net, listview, mfc

For each item in my ListCtrl I would like to have :

- an image
- a title
- a description

For your opinion, it will be easier to do that with .NET ? If yes have you got some examples ?

Ps: with Adobe Flex, I used the ItemRenderer notion to customise easily a list.

Thank you so much guys !

Answer (score 0):

A ListCtrl in supports an image (a small one -- an icon, really), and an arbitrary number of text columns for each item.

The most obvious problem is going to be if you want to display your images full-size. In icon view you get 32x32 pixel icons. In the other modes, you get 16x16 pixel icons.

If that's sufficient, then making things work should be fairly easy. As to whether it'll be easier with .NET -- I'd call it an open question. At least in my opinion, it's likely to depend on which you're more familiar with. If you've used MFC before, then using a list control won't be particularly difficult. On the other hand, if you've used .NET before (and not MFC -- at least recently) there's almost no question that it'll be easier with .NET instead.

If you have no familiarity with either, using .NET will most likely be easier, but not by a huge margin.